# What does a frozen Memtest86+ suggest about the cause of my WIFI troubles?

Tags: wireless-networking, memory, hardware-failure, memtest86+

So for quite a while I've been having trouble with WIFI on my computer; it will sometimes have a really low download/upload speed (down to 0.3MBit/s on my HFC connection), othertimes those speeds will be fine, but ping times will be over 1 second, even up to 3s. Occasionally it seems to completely fail to negotiate with my router's DHCP. The rest of my computer seems to largely be in good health, and I haven't really noticed other recurring problems. I don't think it's blue-screened in over a year, and non-blue-screen crashes don't happen more than once every 3-4 months. The only other issue I can think of is that occasionally my cordless USB keyboard (a Logitech K270) has really laggy keypresses, but I suspect that's the keyboard.

I recently bought a new PCIE WIFI adapter, thinking my old one could be the problem. It is sometimes better, but it hasn't prevented any of the previous problems.

So thinking of other diagnostic tools, I ran Memtest86+ off an Ubuntu live DVD. I was actually pretty shocked that it immediately froze after 9 seconds. I assumed if my RAM was so damaged that it would have presented other problems than slow WIFI. I tried it in both modes it offered at the beginning, and they both froze at approximately the same point.

[image: Photo of Memtest86+ frozen after 9 seconds]

Does this result suggest that I do have faulty RAM, and is that consistent with the problems I've been seeing? Or does a frozen Memtest86 suggest that it may be a faulty motherboard or CPU [as I've seen elsewhere?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1267257/333388)

Comment: It certainly suggest you have a hardware problem.  Have you tried performing the test without the WiFi card installed?

Comment: No, that didn't occur to me. Can certainly try that though.

Comment: That would determine if the WiFi card is the reason for the Memtest86 problems.  Operating systems use system memory to handle files being downloaded.  If the operating system is encountering memory faults, and has to recover from those faults, it could in theory present as a slower download speeds.  However, your ping times, are unlikely related.  Ping times have almost nothing to do with the bandwidth available on a connection.